# Truncated spaces at the end shouldn't be counted when computing the 150-character limit for a question

Tags: bug, questions, title, character-limit

When computing the 150-character limit for a question, the trailing space(s) are counted as part of the question title, even though they'll be truncated away when the question is saved.

For example `Given a stock traded on a public exchange, how can one determine how much of the stock is owned by individual investors (vs. institutional investors)?`  (notice the trailing space) will cause the error:

> Title cannot be longer than 150 characters.

Trailing space(s) shouldn't be counted when computing the 150-character limit for a question, since they'll anyway be truncated away when saved.

Comment: As years are going, I see more and more posts with more and more unneeded spaces. A decade later the posts will contain more spaces than worthy characters. I have no hearth to vote your question down, but I am sure that this is the last for which the SE should spend resources.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica the fix is 1 line of code. Doesn't strike me as requiring much resource. SE already remove the trailing spaces anyway, so this won't increase the amount of unneeded spaces.

Comment: Right. I think people requires some "help" to learn that words and sentences are separated by a single space, and leading/trailing creap of whitespaces serve as a signature of the OP has zero interest to create good posts. I admit, this is not a big problem until most the SO first-posters have a major trouble with the written communication in general (see [functional illiteracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_illiteracy)), but I think we still should not help them.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica the issue happened to me and I have an interest in creating good posts. Congrats on never leaving any trailing spaces.

Comment: @Ollie no offense taken, I prefer to write titles that are sufficient to understand the question. I find it annoying to browse through question titles that are vague (e.g. "stock traded on a public exchange").

Comment: You are a special case. You can read/write on multiple languages on nearly native level. This makes you special among the average SO users. The company, while tries to defend its content from the crap, makes also an undeliberate, but wonderful crusade by fighting illiteracy on the whole world. I think, if the SE had never existed, similar **forums** still would exist, fulfilling its role. But the average literacy level of young wannabe programmers would be far worse.

Comment: Pretty impressed by the number of downvotes on reporting an easy-to-fix bug.

Comment: FYI, looks like it does [let you post the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403626/8967612) regardless of the warning message (as long as the length of the trimmed title is <=150 characters) which means it's definitely a bug. Your question might get a better response if you turn it into a [bug] report instead of a [feature-request] (I'm only guessing here).

Comment: @41686d6564 thx done

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Forms failing to fix basic issues (here, trailing spaces) don't send a positive signal to the users.

Comment: @peterh fun fact: Most people that learned to type on typewriters were taught that two spaces after a sentence is correct. So, it's generally not young wannabe programmers that do this, but people that existed before I was even born!

Comment: Oh the joy of separate client- and server-side checks

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Thanks, it is good to know. However, the 4-8 empty lines before and after their post (sometimes with 4-8 spaces in them all), the 2-4 spaces before and after their all markups, well I think there is no explanation for that, except stupidity. I admit, it is not a big problem, because it annoys only people trying to fix their posts, and not visible in the rendered html. However, I think the correlation between the completely crap post and the excess spaces is about 80-90% (subjective estimation, based on some years of cleanup).

Comment: Is it the same for [full stop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/full_stop#Noun) at the end of titles (which, BTW, ***shouldn't*** be applied to "[etc.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/etc.#Phrase)". But it is, unfortunately)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize the answers the question received in the comments: 1) trailing spaces are a reflection of the OP's stupidity and we don't want such users 2) the resources that Stack Exchange would spend in removing trailing spaces would be better spent somewhere else.

Relevant comments:

> - As years are going, I see more and more posts with more and more unneeded spaces. A decade later the posts will contain more spaces than worthy characters. I have no hearth to vote your question down, but I am sure that this is the last for which the SE should spend resources. – [peterh - Reinstate Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259412/peterh-reinstate-monica) [Dec 12 at 22:49](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357803/truncated-spaces-at-the-end-shouldnt-be-counted-when-computing-the-150-characte#comment1195345_357803)
> - Right. I think people requires some "help" to learn that words and sentences are separated by a single space, and leading/trailing creap of whitespaces serve as a signature of the OP has zero interest to create good posts. I admit, this is not a big problem until most the SO first-posters have a major trouble with the written communication in general (see [functional illiteracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_illiteracy)), but I think we still should not help them. – [peterh - Reinstate Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259412/peterh-reinstate-monica) [Dec 12 at 22:56](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357803/truncated-spaces-at-the-end-shouldnt-be-counted-when-computing-the-150-characte#comment1195348_357803)

I disagree, but the large ratio of downvotes:upvotes (13:5 currently) seems to indicate I'm in the minority.